# Simplify ViewState by removing Reloading state and just using Loading state

Tags: android, android-binding-adapter

I do not want to hide RecyclerView when I am refreshing using SwipeRefreshLayout. As a result I introduced Reloading state in my ViewState class :

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    class Loading<out T> : Resource<T>()
    class Reloading<out T> : Resource<T>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T?) : Resource<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val cause: String?) : Resource<T>()
}
```

And here is my binding Adapters :

```
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("refreshing")
    fun setSwipeRefreshLayout(view: SwipeRefreshLayout, resource: Resource<*>?) {
        view.isRefreshing = resource is Resource.Loading || resource is Resource.Reloading
        view.isEnabled = resource !is Resource.Failure
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("showError")
    fun showError(view: View, resource: Resource<*>?) {
        view.visibility = if (resource is Resource.Failure) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("showData")
    fun showData(view: RecyclerView, resource: Resource<*>?) {
        view.visibility = if (resource is Resource.Reloading || resource is Resource.Success)
            View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

    }
```

Is there any solution to simplify ViewState classes and remove Reloading state (by just using Loading state)?
Source code can be found here : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/SavingGoals-Cache

Comment: I'm not familiar with Biding Adapter, but from my view, you can replace `class Loading` with `data class Loading(val isRefreshing: Boolean)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easiest way to cut off `Reloading state` and add boolean indicator to `Loading state`:

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    data class Loading<out T>(val isRefreshing: Boolean) : Resource<T>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T?) : Resource<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val cause: String?) : Resource<T>()
}
```